Double rendering (race condition) from action cable and turbo streams
Maybe I am missing something here but it looks like if you are using Turbo and Action Cable in Rails 7, you could with a race condition by broadcasting to yourself.
For example, let's say that I have a todo list and when you add an item, there is a create.turbo_stream.erb that does a turbo_stream.append 'todoList', partial: ....
So when you add an item it gets appended to #todoList, fine.
BUT let's say you also have an action cable or Turbo::StreamsChannel broadcast that happens after_create, like this:
Turbo::StreamsChannel.broadcast_append_to('todo-stream', {
  target: 'todoList',
  partial: 'todo',
  locals: { todo: todo }
})

So now what happens is that the create.turbo_stream.html appends the item and then broadcast ALSO appends the element to the todo list!
I was under the assumption that the broadcast would be "smart" enough to know that the client who triggered the broadcast should not receive the broadcast, but that doesnt seem to be the case.
So how can I handle this?  I cant just replace the create.turbo_stream.html file with the broadcast as more complex methods, such as dropzone.js or sortable.js, result in having the final element in a certain place, so broadcasting a replacement doesnt make sense.

I'm voting to close this one as it was resolved in a way that's not directly connected to the original question. Please consider deleting it as these kind of questions are not really helpful to others.

@max I strongly disagree.  alex's answer was completely approprite for the question and helped me solve it.  Without this others may run into the same issue.

First, make sure you have a unique id for your todo partial, this will prevent appending duplicated elements and replace them instead:
# app/views/todos/_todo.html.erb

<%= tag.div id: dom_id(todo) do %>
  # ...
<% end %>


If the template’s first element has an id that is already used by a direct child inside the container targeted by dom_id, it is replaced instead of appended.

https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/streams#append

If replacing a duplicated id is somehow causing an issue, the only solution I've found is to replicate what refresh action does by tracking current request id:
class Todo < ApplicationRecord
  # this will broadcast a turbo stream with request id attribute:
  #   <turbo-stream request-id="b3937918-30cb-47de-8bb0-020ac0d5c2dd" action="append" target="todos">
  #     ...
  #   </turbo-stream>
  after_create_commit do
    broadcast_append_to(:todos, attributes: {"request-id": Turbo.current_request_id})
  end
end

# app/controllers/todos_controller.rb

def create
  @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)
  if @todo.save
    render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.append(:todos, @todo)
  end
end

The request id is sent from the front end as X-Turbo-Request-Id header.
When this turbo stream arrives you need to compare request-id attribute with a recent request. If there is a match that means turbo stream came from a broadcast that you've initiated and can be ignored:
// app/javascript/application.js

const originalAppend = Turbo.StreamActions.append

// override append action and do what the `refresh` action does:
Turbo.StreamActions.append = function() {
  const session = Turbo.session
  const isRecentRequest = this.requestId && session.recentRequests.has(this.requestId)
  if (!isRecentRequest && !session.navigator.currentVisit) {
    originalAppend.bind(this).call()
  }
}

https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/blob/v8.0.5/src/core/streams/stream_actions.js#L52
https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/blob/v8.0.5/src/core/session.js#L110

wow.  truly wonderfully wow.  So this ALMOST worked but at no fault of yours.  The problem is that I was making the server post with FETCH since I am using sortable.js to update the list.  Thats the use case.  So using the above as a guide what I ended up doing was replacing fetch with Turbo.fetch,, which then let me retrieve the Turbo.current_request_id and pass i back down to a custom Stream Action that handles the rest.  Thank you!
